# Rstudio Shortcut to Restart R Session + Run All

Tags: r, rstudio, shortcut

In RStudio there is a shortcut for Restart Session (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F10</kbd>) and another one for Run All (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + R</kbd>), but I often want to do the first one followed by the second one, like in other environments like Jupyter Notebooks.

[I see there's no such an option in the RStudio shortcuts](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/reference/shortcuts.html#source).

Does anyone know how if there's this two actions put together in one or there's a way to add this handy shortcut to RStudio?

Maybe a way to build the shortcut would be to use [rstudioapi](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/) to restart the session and then use the R command "source" to run the script which Rstudio uses to run the script: `source("~/.active-rstudio-document", echo=TRUE)`

I looked for information or references in internet but I just found a call through the rstudioapi to restart the R session inside RStudio and a reference of all RStudio shortcuts not including the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Try `.rs.restartR()`.

Comment: I found there's an option in Rstudio to set a keybinding for "Restart R Session and Run All Chunks", but for some reason it doesn't work for me :S. I'm in Ubuntu 20.04 and RStudio 2023.09.1

Comment: OK, I found out that the shortcut "Restart R Session and Run All Chunks"" applies only to .Rmd documents, so I'm looking for the same but for R Scripts.

Comment: Why bothering with RStudio, use [Rcript](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/Rscript) or the respective Windows equivalent.